# Need help about android mounting Sdcard

Tags: android

Im working on "mount ntfs sdcard"
That is problem:
- If i mount sdcard to **another folder** than **/mtn/sdcard** then my sdcard working find
- If i mount it to **/mnt/sdcard** then android not except it : " The  SDcard is not currently mounted"
  In **adb shell** i type **mount** command and see that my SDcard is **mounted** to **/mnt/sdcard**

But infact SDcard folder cannot accessable.
I think android doesnt except mount **ntfs** sdcard on **/mnt/sdcard** because it programed to mount **vfat** sdcard on /mnt/sdcard.

Now the question: where i can find mounting code or mounting procedure of android when we insert SDcard? i want to modify it to accept ntfs sdcard.

P/S: im on GB 2.3.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very specific question, I doubt you will get an answer here. You might want to try to locate it yourself from the source code which could be found here:

https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/opensource/download

I did some googling and found this:

http://cateee.net/lkddb/web-lkddb/NTFS_FS.html, you might need to modify it.

Comment: thank you. And look into a 2.1Gigabyte source code XD so i should start finding it immediately

Comment: Im done with kernel. My kernel is support ntfs and i can use ntfs sdcard with read-writeable. All i want is mount it to where android mount an FAT sdcard so many apk can direct access to ntfs sdcard like Camera app to recode a video clip. Because i cant mount ntfs sdcard to /mnt/sdcard so Camera app cannot recode clip

Answer (score 1):

On Android, the mounting of the sdcard is managed by the vold daemon.

If you want a stable system, you likely need to either get vold to manage your custom mount, remove vold from the system and do it's entire job yourself, or somehow get it and your custom solution to stay out of each other's way.

Lots of custom ROMs have used vold in different ways - to partition an sdcard and add a unix-style filesystem for storing apps, to put an entire alternate android installation on an sdcard or tablet internal storage area, etc.  You might get some ideas by looking at those, reading their development discussion history, etc.

Comment: Thanks, How to change the owner of vfat mount?

Comment: That's not something you should try to do on Android.